# How to use pyautogui on macOS to control Macbook Air keyboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, arduino, pyautogui

I am trying to use pyautogui with Arduino connected to the Paj7620 gesture sensor module on Macbook Air M1 running Sonoma (14.0). The problem is pyautogui doesn't seem to trigger the action despite the correct value has been passed to the Python code. I already allowed the Terminal in the Privacy & Security -> Accessibility as well.

Here, for example, is the Python code:

```
import serial #Serial imported for Serial communication
import time #Required to use delay functions
import pyautogui

ArduinoSerial = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem11401',9600) #Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData
time.sleep(2) #wait for 2 seconds for the communication to get established

while 1:
    incoming = str(ArduinoSerial.readline()) #read the serial data and print it as line
    print(incoming)
    
    if 'Right' in incoming:
        pyautogui.press('nexttrack')

    if 'Left' in incoming:
        pyautogui.press('prevtrack')  

    if 'Up' in incoming:
        pyautogui.press('volumeup') 

    if 'Down' in incoming:
        pyautogui.press('volumedown')
        
    if 'Forward' in incoming:
        pyautogui.press('pause')

    if 'Backward' in incoming:
        pyautogui.press('playpause')

    incoming = "";
```

And here is the program output:

```
b'PAJ7620U2 TEST DEMO: Recognize 9 gestures.\r\n'
b'INIT SENSOR...\r\n'
b'Addr0 =20,  Addr1 =76\r\n'
b'wake-up finish.\r\n'
b'Paj7620 initialize register finished.\r\n'
b'INIT OK\r\n'
b'Please input your gestures:\n'
b'\r\n'
b'Right\r\n'
b'Left\r\n'
b'Forward\r\n'
b'Backward\r\n'
b'Up\r\n'
b'Forward\r\n'
...
```

Using the same code, calling spotify (https://github.com/hnarayanan/shpotify) works really well, but it would be good if I can control any media player and not just spotify.

Answer (score 0):

Recently experienced some issues with pyautogui. Try to run your script using root user like so:

```
sudo python your_script.py
```

Mac os has different blocks with system interactions via python.

Comment: Thank you so much Ilya, I have tried using root as well but unfortunately it doesn't seems to be working.